# Can signing executables prevent antivirus quarantining?

Tags: c#, antivirus, false-positive

My C# application is being quarantined by Symantec. If I sign my application with a good certificate, will it prevent this?

Comment: That would most likely depend on what it is quarantined _for_. Do you get any message stating what it finds suspicious?

Comment: What type of application you have created ? Is it doing something that is not permitted by Symantec ?

Comment: It says the application is new and it has not been seen before.

Comment: My application requires administratives privileges for writing one thing in the registry and replace some files in the %program files%

Comment: It's being classified as suspicious by Symantec http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2010-021223-0550-99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're being rated as suspicious, the quickest way to resolve it would probably be to [submit a white listing request](https://submit.symantec.com/whitelist/).

Since the software has been deemed suspicious by a heuristic/reputation based system, there's no guarantee that signing it will automatically white list it (although it will most likely raise the possibility)